# TypeScript function with generic parameter which uses computed keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have two functions which do the same thing, the only difference is the types. I want to use generic types together with computed properties, but can't wrap my head around which types/interfaces need to extend which. This is what I want to do:

```js
const getUpdatedState = <T, K>(state: T, column: K) => {
    return {...state, [column]: state[column] === 'unsorted' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'}
}
```

This obviously does not work, because `T` can have different properties. Is there a way of doing this with generic types?

Here's the types and the actual code:

Types:

```js
export type DMessageKeys =
    | 'conversationId'
    | 'created'
    | 'lastUpdate'
    | 'serviceIdentifier'
    | 'senderIdentifier'
    | 'receiverIdentifier'
    | 'latestMessageStatus'

export type DSortingState = {
    [key in DMessageKeys]: Sorts
}

export type EMessageKeys =
    | 'conversationId'
    | 'externalId'
    | 'lastUpdated'
    | 'createdDate'
    | 'sendingStatus'

export type ESortingState = {
    [key in EMessageKeys]: Sorts
}

export type Sorts = 'unsorted' | 'ascending' | 'descending'
```

and the functions:

```js
export const getUpdatedDSortingState = (
    initialState: DSortingState,
    currentState: DSortingState,
    column: DMessageKeys
): DSortingState => {
    return {
        ...initialState,
        [column]:
            currentState[column] === 'unsorted' || currentState[column] === 'descending'
                ? 'ascending'
                : 'descending',
    }
}

export const getUpdatedESortingState = (
    initialState: ESortingState,
    currentState: EsortingState,
    column: EMessageKeys
): ESortingState => {
    return {
        ...initialState,
        [column]:
            currentState[column] === 'unsorted' || currentState[column] === 'descending'
                ? 'ascending'
                : 'descending',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct this should do it.

```
const getUpdatedState = <T, K>(state: T, column: K) : any => { // you can also set the real types with "typeX | typeY"
    return {...state, [column]: state[column] === 'unsorted' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'}
}

const updatedState = getUpdateState<type1, type2>(state, column);
```

Comment: This is too simple. You can't use `K` to index `T`. I'm guessing the generic types must extend some common type, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it (if possible at all)